# How to Sort an ArrayList of arraylist in java?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, collections, comparator

I want to sort an ArrayList of ArrayList.
How can I use custom comparator in Collections.sort();
???
my IDE shows error

`ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> A`

`Collections.sort(A,new Comparator<ArrayList<Integer>>(){    });`
the above code is not working

Comment: @NielsNet that is not working here

Comment: do you need to get an ArrayList<Integer> or an  ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> ?

Comment: @imperezivan later one

Comment: Sort by what???

Comment: @shmosel The first element of each array list

Comment: `A.sort(Comparator.comparing(list -> list.get(0)));`

Comment: @shmosel what should I google to learn about this statement

Comment: Try "java 8 sorting" or something. Here's an article: https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-sort-lambda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a single sorted list you can try this :

```
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> myListOfList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> sortedList = myListOfList.stream()
            .flatMap(List::stream)
            .sorted(Integer::compareTo)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or this :

```
    List<Integer> sortedList = myListOfList.stream()
            .flatMap(List::stream)
            .sorted(Comparator.naturalOrder())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I want the output as ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>